# Java MVC: updating View that observes multiple Models

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, design-patterns

In my MVC application I display a chart, using Swing. It is controlled by multiple panels with different settings.  I have `MainModel` to build and feed the `DomainObject` that `ChartView` outputs. Since there are multiple panels and I didnt want to make `MainModel` huge, it creates `ChildModels` for each panel with their own views. In turn, `MainController` attaches `ChildControllers` to them. 'ChartView' registers itself to observe changes in `MainModel` to update the output.

The first problem is that since `ChildModels` are basically parts of `MainModel`, their changes have to trigger updates on `ChartView` (besides their own views). To solve this I had to make `MainModel` register its children with `ChartView` manually. So, now I have multiple models attached to  `ChartView`. Although I know this probably caused by bad design (model that creates child models and so on), the solution worked ok. But I'd like to hear other approaches to breaking up one big model. I had this one idea to have `MainModel`  listen to changes in `ChildModels` and notify `ChartView`. This way only one model is communicating with `ChartView`.

The second problem is chain-triggering of `ChartView` updates. It happens because all these panels with settings have some values that depend on each other. So, if user enters some value in `first panel`, the range which a value from `second panel` can take changes. When controller updates `second panel` it triggers `StateChange Event`. And since `ChartView` was subsribed to listen to updates on `ChildModels` it will receive update notification from both panels. Now, in my case I have 8 of those. That makes one single input from user resulting in 8 `ChartView` redrawings. Which, probably, again is a result of poor design. But in this case I have no idea how to handle correctly these multiple update notifications and make `GraphView` only update on last request. My solution was to make transactional updates. Instead of single notification to view, models send `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` notifications. Only after view receives `endUpdate` it queries model for updated data. This way nested model update notifications are sort of "muted".

I would like to know how you approach these problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your concern, the error is to have `ChartView` listening to several models at the same time. MVC assumes there is only one model. So `ChartView` should connect *only* to `MainModel`. The goal of `MainModel` is to multiplex correctly the changes coming from the panels, and to dispatch events to `ChartView`. Your idea to have `MainModel` listening to the child models and serving `ChartView` looks like the correct design for me.

About your second question, a common usage consists in a boolean parameter (e.g. `multiple`) in the event. The value `true` indicates that the next event is part of a sequence and `false` means the sequence is over. If the event is not part of a sequence, set the parameter to `false` (which means a sequence of length 1). In your use case, simply ignore events with `true` and wait for `false` events to query the stable state.

Comment: You mention that "MVC assumes there is only one model." A `JTable`, for example, may have a data model, a column model, a selection model, etc. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Here when you talk about data/column/selection models, you are actually talking about 3 different MVC instances, even if they contribute to the same swing component.

Comment: Also I said that the View must be connected to at most one Model at a time, because the role of the MVC patttern is to connect a view to a model, not to multiplex input from different sources. This kind of functionality should be implemented at the model level, to leave the view out of this arbitrary complexity.